# strange "! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end" error

Tags: luatex

I wrote a [book](https://github.com/somenxavier/apunts-acces-uib-per-a-majors-de-25-anys) in Lualatex. No problem with compilation but now I want to recompile and I get this:

```
[2<./graphics/ccbygran-eps-converted-to.pdf>]

LaTeX Warning: Reference `fig:diagrama-arbre-0' on page 3 undefined on input li
ne 28.

) [3] [4]

! LaTeX Error: There's no line here to end.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.206 \tableofcontents

?
```

It seems that I have a extra line, but if you see previous [compiled version](https://github.com/somenxavier/apunts-acces-uib-per-a-majors-de-25-anys/blob/master/apunts.pdf) (I have not touched anything since then except putting `\RequirePackage{luatex85}` in the very beginning of the [main document](https://github.com/somenxavier/apunts-acces-uib-per-a-majors-de-25-anys/blob/master/apunts.tex)), you see that the error is after page 4 (which corresponds to file [`drets d'autor`](https://github.com/somenxavier/apunts-acces-uib-per-a-majors-de-25-anys/blob/master/02-drets-d-autor.tex)).

So, I have no clue why I have this error. Before answer, try to compile to code, please.

Comment: Try to clean aux files and compile again.

Comment: Usually the error is due to misusing ``\\`` for "leaving a blank line"

Comment: it is unlikely to be related to a luatex update, using `\\ ` when there is no line has always been an error. Look for a `\\ ` at the start of a paragraph. (probably in your table of contents, so you could delete the `.toc` file and let latex re-create it)

Comment: @Sigur: same error without .aux files

Comment: How can I search \\ in all my files? `grep -r --color "\\"` gives me error. And more important, how to know which gives me error. And why before I have not errot and now I have

Comment: What error? (In general, please note that saying 'gives me error' is too vague for people to help.) Did you specify any files to `grep`? Maybe try something like `grep -rn --color '\\\\' *tex`? And of course your editor should allow you to search the file it has open for editing.

Comment: As it stands this question is far too vague: we need to see the _actual code_ creating the issue (`\tableofcontents` certainly works with LuaTeX). I've refunded the bounty pending a clearer statement of the issue.

Comment: @Joseph Wright: The code is [here](https://github.com/somenxavier/apunts-acces-uib-per-a-majors-de-25-anys) as I stated in the question

Comment: @somenxavier I see one isolated line in the question, which in itself won't give the error stated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is one of those cases where building a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) would have let you easily isolate the source of the error.

Now, just giving us a link to a GitHub repo with a bunch of files isn't very nice, but seeing as I didn't have anything better to do this morning, the following reproduces the problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{headingcolor}{cmyk}{1,0.5431,0,0.5451}
\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[hang] % shape
{\huge} % format
{\color{headingcolor}\itshape\bfseries\LARGE\thechapter} % label
{1ex} % sep
{
    \centering
    \\  %%%%%%%%%%%%% <- remove this
    \color{headingcolor}
} % before-code
[
\vspace{5cm}
] % after-code

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\end{document}
```

And the cause is that you have the `\\` after `\centering`. Remove that, and it works fine. Note that you should use `\itshape`, not `\it`.

Here is a version which places the number and chapter name on separate lines:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{headingcolor}{cmyk}{1,0.5431,0,0.5451}
\titleformat
{\chapter} % command
[hang] % shape
{\huge} % format
{\color{headingcolor}\itshape\bfseries\LARGE\thechapter} % label
{0ex} % sep %% changed to 0
{% <-- added
    \centering~\\[1ex]
    \color{headingcolor}%
} % before-code
[
\vspace{1cm}
] % after-code

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\chapter{Funky}
Lorem ipsum.
\end{document}
```

Comment: But really, when you get an error you don't understand, isolate the cause by making an MWE, and if that doesn't help you solve it, then come ask with the MWE, please don't just dump your entire project in our lap.

Comment: Someways it's impossible to do a minimal example because you don't know what fails here. By this reason I asked help. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The question is why before it is OK and now I received an error.

Comment: So, how to get a line between the number and the chapter title in `titleformat`?

Comment: @somenxavier -- you need to put something on that line so it's not empty.  `\phantom{x}` would work.  so would `$ $` (note the space between the `$` signs.  obviously, what you put on the line should be invisible.

Comment: @somenxavier Sorry, I forgot to consider that you said it had worked before. Strange that you experienced that though, for example the error occurs also with `pdflatex`. That said, the point of making an MWE is precisely to try to figure out what fails.  So you could surely have done the same as I did, and come up with the same or a similar example as I did above.

Comment: @barbarabeeton: it does not work with ` \centerin \phantom{x} \\
    \color{headingcolor}`

Comment: @somenxavier -- `\phantom` indeed doesn't  work, but `\hspace*{1cm}` does.  (when i posted the earlier comment, i wasn't able to test; i've just tested.  not sure why `\phantom` doesn't work; conceptually it should.  tracing shows that it's hanging up while trying to expand `\color`, but that's as far as i've gotten, and am not inclined to dig deeper.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton Better `vspace` because I want vertical space.

Comment: @somenxavier -- `\vspace` is reasonable.  i suggest using `\vspace*` to keep it from disappearing at the top of a page.  (not tested, but since `\chapter` is involved, it quite possibly starts at the top of a page.)

Comment: @barbarabeeton it does not work. Only horizontal space is added.

Comment: @somenxavier `$ $` works as well, but see the edit to my answer.